# Play! Framework: Scala code inside play. scala.html template

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.2, playframework-2.3

I have a table in scala.html. Inside that table I need to compare if a certain string is equal to the yesterday's date. So I need to use a Scala code inside the template file.

```
    <table class="testResults zebra-striped" id="table1">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        @header("hssBuildNumber", "Build #")
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                   @for(jobResult <- currentPage) {

                     <td>                
                        @{
                          var date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000L * 60L * 60L * 24L);
                          var formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                          var yesterday = formatter.format(date).toString();

                          @if(jobResult.hssBuildNumber.contains(yesterday)){
                             //do smth..
                          }
                       }
                     </td>
                    }

                </tbody>
    </table>
```

This doesn't work. Compilation error: not found: value yesterday.
I will appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you need to pass your value, i believe, http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaTemplates#Declaring-reusable-values

You may also consider normalizing your code to following one-liner:

```
@if(jobResult.hssBuildNumber.contains(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000L * 60L * 60L * 24L)))){
```

Comment: Great! Thanks. One-liner worked. But still it's not very clear how to inject a code with multiple lines and call the variables later in the code.